# The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized

Tags: c#, gmail, http-status-code-401, networkcredentials

I am extracting gmail contacts using [opencontactsnet](http://sourceforge.net/projects/opencontactsnet/). I get `The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.` when executing this line

`HttpWebResponse exportResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) contactsRequest.GetResponse();`

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Data;
using System.Net;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using OpenContactsNet;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page 
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GmailExtract gm = new GmailExtract();
        NetworkCredential nw = new NetworkCredential("chendur.pandiya","**");
        MailContactList mc;
        if (gm.Extract(nw, out mc))
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
     }
}
```

Here is the complete `GmailExtract` class,

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using Utilities.Web;

namespace OpenContactsNet
{
    public class GmailExtract : IMailContactExtract
    {
        private const string ContinueUrl = "http://mail.google.com/mail?ui=html&amp;zy=l";
        private const string ExportUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/contacts/data/export?exportType=ALL&groupToExport=&out=GMAIL_CSV";
        private const string LoginRefererUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fui%3Dhtml%26zy%3Dl&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2";
        private const string LoginUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=mail";
        private const string UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; EmbeddedWB 14.52 from: http://www.bsalsa.com/ EmbeddedWB 14.52; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; InfoPath.1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30)";

        #region IMailContactExtract Members

        public bool Extract( NetworkCredential credential, out MailContactList list )
        {
            bool result = false;
            list = new MailContactList();

            try
            {
                CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

                // Prepare login form data
                HttpValueCollection loginFormValues = new HttpValueCollection();
                loginFormValues[ "ltmpl" ] = "default";
                loginFormValues[ "ltmplcache" ] = "2";
                loginFormValues[ "continue" ] = ContinueUrl;
                loginFormValues[ "service" ] = "mail";
                loginFormValues[ "rm" ] = "false";
                loginFormValues[ "hl" ] = "en";
                loginFormValues[ "Email" ] = credential.UserName;
                loginFormValues[ "Passwd" ] = credential.Password;
                loginFormValues[ "PersistentCookie" ] = "true";
                loginFormValues[ "rmShown" ] = "1";
                loginFormValues[ "null" ] = "Sign In";

                // Convert to bytes
                byte[] loginPostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( loginFormValues.ToString( true ) );

                HttpWebRequest loginRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( LoginUrl );
                loginRequest.Method = "POST";
                loginRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                loginRequest.Referer = LoginRefererUrl;
                loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                loginRequest.ContentLength = loginPostData.Length;
                loginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

                // Create cookie container
                loginRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();

                // Add post data to request
                Stream stream;
                using ( stream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream() )
                {
                    stream.Write( loginPostData, 0, loginPostData.Length );
                }

                HttpWebResponse loginResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) loginRequest.GetResponse();

                cookies.Add( loginResponse.Cookies );

                // Create request to export Google CSV page
                HttpWebRequest contactsRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( ExportUrl );
                contactsRequest.Method = "GET";
                contactsRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                contactsRequest.Referer = loginResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();

                // use cookie gotten from login page
                contactsRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                foreach ( Cookie cookie in cookies )
                {
                    contactsRequest.CookieContainer.Add( cookie );
                }

                HttpWebResponse exportResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) contactsRequest.GetResponse();

                // Read data from response stream
                string csvData;
                using ( Stream responseStream = exportResponse.GetResponseStream() )
                {
                    using ( StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader( responseStream ) )
                    {
                        csvData = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                // parse google csv
                string[] lines = csvData.Split( '\n' );
                foreach ( string line in lines )
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split( ',' );
                    if ( values.Length < 2 )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    MailContact mailContact = new MailContact();
                    mailContact.Email = values[ 1 ];
                    mailContact.Name = values[ 0 ];
                    list.Add( mailContact );
                }

                result = true;
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                throw e;
            }

            return result;
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into the same problem. I had to change the `GmailExtract` class in opencontactsnet. Below is the new code which works for me.

```
public class GmailExtract : IMailContactExtract
    {
        private const string ContinueUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/?"; 
        private const string ExportUrl = "https://mail.google.com/mail/contacts/data/export?exportType=ALL&groupToExport=&out=GMAIL_CSV";
        private const string LoginRefererUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fui%3Dhtml%26zy%3Dl&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2";
        private const string LoginUrl = "https://www.google.com/accounts/ServiceLoginAuth?service=mail";
        private const string UserAgent = "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)";

        #region IMailContactExtract Members

        public bool Extract( NetworkCredential credential, out MailContactList list)
        {
            bool result = false;
            list = new MailContactList();

            DateTime jsStartDate = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1);
            TimeSpan endTs = DateTime.Now.Subtract(jsStartDate);
            TimeSpan startTs = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(-2).Subtract(jsStartDate);

            try
            {
                CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();

                // Prepare login form data
                HttpValueCollection loginFormValues = new HttpValueCollection();
                loginFormValues["Email"] = credential.UserName;
                loginFormValues["Passwd"] = credential.Password;
                loginFormValues["asts"] = "";
                loginFormValues["continue"] = ContinueUrl;
                loginFormValues["dsh"] = "1461574034599761425";
                loginFormValues["hl"] = "en";
                loginFormValues["ltmpl"] = "default";
                loginFormValues["ltmplcache"] = "2";
                loginFormValues["rm"] = "false";
                loginFormValues["rmShown"] = "1";
                loginFormValues["service"] = "mail";
                loginFormValues["signIn"] = "Sign In";
                loginFormValues["scc"] = "1";
                loginFormValues["ss"] = "1";
                loginFormValues["GALX"] = "rBTUs4OAJBI";
                loginFormValues["ltmpl"] = "default";
                loginFormValues["ltmpl"] = "default";

                // Convert to bytes
                byte[] loginPostData = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( loginFormValues.ToString( true ) );

                HttpWebRequest loginRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( LoginUrl );
                loginRequest.Method = "POST";
                loginRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                loginRequest.Referer = LoginRefererUrl;
                loginRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
                loginRequest.ContentLength = loginPostData.Length;
                loginRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

                // Create cookie container
                loginRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                loginRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("GMAIL_LOGIN", "T" + startTs.Milliseconds.ToString() + "/" + startTs.Milliseconds.ToString() + "/" + endTs.Milliseconds.ToString(), "/", ".google.com"));
                loginRequest.CookieContainer.Add(new Cookie("GALX", "rBTUs4OAJBI", "/accounts", ".google.com"));

                // Add post data to request
                Stream stream;
                using ( stream = loginRequest.GetRequestStream())
                {
                    stream.Write( loginPostData, 0, loginPostData.Length);
                }

                HttpWebResponse loginResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) loginRequest.GetResponse();

                cookies.Add( loginResponse.Cookies );

                // Create request to export Google CSV page
                HttpWebRequest contactsRequest = ( HttpWebRequest ) WebRequest.Create( ExportUrl );
                contactsRequest.Method = "GET";
                contactsRequest.UserAgent = UserAgent;
                contactsRequest.Referer = loginResponse.ResponseUri.ToString();

                // use cookie gotten from login page
                contactsRequest.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
                foreach ( Cookie cookie in cookies )
                {
                    contactsRequest.CookieContainer.Add( cookie );
                }

                HttpWebResponse exportResponse = ( HttpWebResponse ) contactsRequest.GetResponse();

                // Read data from response stream
                string csvData;
                using ( Stream responseStream = exportResponse.GetResponseStream())
                {
                    using ( StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader( responseStream ) )
                    {
                        csvData = streamRead.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }

                // parse google csv
                string[] lines = csvData.Split( '\n' );
                foreach ( string line in lines )
                {
                    string[] values = line.Split( ',' );
                    if ( values.Length < 2 )
                    {
                        continue;
                    }

                    MailContact mailContact = new MailContact();
                    mailContact.Email = values[ 28 ];
                    mailContact.Name = values[ 0 ];
                    if (mailContact.Email.Trim().Length > 0)
                    {

                         list.Add(mailContact);

                    }
                }

                result = true;
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            return result;
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Comment: @Ajay The name 'Common' does not exist in the current context

Comment: Oops!! sorry for that. I had put a email validation code. Now I have removed that line of code. Please try again

Comment: can you please check. I had removed the if statement i.e. if (Common.IsValidEmail(mailContact.Email))

Comment: @ajay i ve checked still the same error with exportURL https://mail.google.com/mail/contacts/data/export?exportType=ALL&groupToExport=&out=GMAIL_CSV

Comment: @Pandiya sorry my bad... had copied the old code... now i have updated it with the correct one.. pls try now.. hope it should work :D

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with google's api nor do I know C#.
However check the URL you are sending your form to. 
Looks like your authentication works. Otherwise you would have recieved a 403. 
401 means that you (as an authenticated user) are not allowed to access the requested resource.

Comment: @user407838 ya you are right My exportUrl failed https://mail.google.com/mail/contacts/data/export?exportType=ALL&groupToExport=&out=GMAIL_CSV

Answer (score 0):

**10.4.2 401 Unauthorized**

The request requires user authentication. The response MUST include a WWW-Authenticate header field (section 14.47) containing a challenge applicable to the requested resource. The client MAY repeat the request with a suitable Authorization header field (section 14.8). **If the request already included Authorization credentials, then the 401 response indicates that authorization has been refused for those credentials.** If the 401 response contains the same challenge as the prior response, and the user agent has already attempted authentication at least once, then *the user SHOULD be presented the entity that was given in the response, since that entity might include relevant diagnostic information.*

Is the `LoginRefererUrl` correctly formed? As that address isn't found on google servers however the correctly formed version signs me straight into my mail box.